# How to access to reference field content with firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm wondering how can I access to the content of a reference field.
I'm learning how to use firebase. I have collections called `places`, `users` and reviews.

I did a first job getting all the `reviews` linked to a `place` document by adding a string field on each review with the id of the place related.

But I wanted to try using the reference field, so on `review` documents, I have a reference field called "user", containing the path (ex: `users/quentin-dupuy`).

But I don't succeed in accessing the content, I understand it contains only a ref, so I can't use it directly like `review.data().user.data().name` or something like that.

Ideally, I guess I'd need to do a getDoc with the path which is in the reference field, but I don't succeed. Also, is the reference field the right one for this kind of thing?

Comment: Document reference fields are not automatically loaded. You will need to perform a separate call to the database API to get the data for each of them. If you're struggling to make that work, edit your question to [show where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.